# refresh the div containing include to other php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Through some time after working hardly on a chat room I'm in a sort of problem.
To understand the problem i'll first tell how the files are connected..
So I have main index.php and a login page a main_index page and user_list page, function file.
Now the main_index has a div which looks something like this

```
<div style="height:92%;overflow-y:  scroll;" id="on">
  <?php include('user_list.php'); ?>
</div>
```

Now what im trying to achieve here is that I want to refresh the online user list, echoed on user_list.php
but if im not wrong that could only be done by using Jquery.
So I have written this Jquery code in the same page

```
  setInterval(function(){
    $('#on').load('user_list.php');
  }, 3000);
```

Now it works absolutely fine... but the problem comes after 3 seconds, on the second refresh, the program gives me the error that it cant find the function "isOwner();" (Written in the user_list.php).

The file structure is as follow

### **Main Directory**

- index.php

**Libs**

- **core** > function.php
- login.php
- main_index.php
- user_list.php

Comment: Can you include the content of user_list.php so we can see exactly what is being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you imported or created isOwner(){} function in index.php, so when you include user_list.php in index.php, it's not shows error, because it's already imported in index.php. But when you try to call in jquery, it shows error, because you did not import isOwner. You need to import this function in user_list.php.

For detailed information we need to see content of user_list.php